# How to load a txt file from a swf coded in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I understand I'm asking something old like my granny but I don't want to lose a decade of hard work on this stuff. Several years ago I started to code a software in Flash to create boardgame maps. It was a simple drag&drop in AS3. Year by year it grew becoming a maze of 30.000 lines and 25Mb of images. I myself have many difficulties to find a single line inside that hell. :)

This software is portable and runs locally. There are two versions: exe for Win machines and swf for every browser with a Flash Player installed. Now, you know that Flash has been year after year treated like a demon and Chrome for example doesn't load it anymore. Other browser like Explorer still can anyway.

Everything has been running correctly till now, when one person contacted me because the swf doesn't work anymore. The EXE version is still running smoothly (it has a Flash Player 10 embedded).

After a whole day I finally managed to find the problem: the swf doesn't load automatically any more txt files placed into the same folder of the swf but it preformed greatly during these years.

Here is the core code that I use (AS3):

```
function LoadConfiguration():void
{
    var ConfigLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    ConfigLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, LoadConfig, false, 0, true);
    ConfigLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,loadingConfigError);
    ConfigLoader.load(new URLRequest("Configuration.txt"));
}
```

I searched everywhere and it is what many suggest to do. And in any cases it worked for many years.

Maybe some recent changes in security prevents flash applications to load a txt file? Is there a workaround for this? I can load a txt file if I open the folder a select it from inside the swf but this is not what I need.

EDIT: all features are on again if I set as trusted the folder where the swf file is placed.

https://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04a.html

This is more a workaround, waiting to change some settings.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the script, nor any security rules that prevent loading things from the same folder. You should probably subscribe to all relevant events (SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR and maybe HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS) then output them all into debug text panel to understand what really happens there.

Comment: Running an SWF application from local folder is the most restricted (in security terms) and should not be done otherwise than in testing purposes.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong but I believe that relative paths (like in your case) don't refer to the directory where the swf resides in but to the directory of the HTML page that embeds the swf. For example you have a page under domain.com/myfolder/index.html. That page loads an swf from domain.com/myfolder/myswf/flash.swf (so from a subfolder named myswf). In this case the Configuration.txt should be under the "myfolder" folder and not under "myfolder/myswf" because that is where the web page is in.

Comment: @Philarmon You are correct. Relative URLs are tricky if HTML and SWF are in different folders.